# What are those tiny potato looking things on morning glories?

Tags: identification, diagnosis

I’ve encountered small brown blobs growing off of some morning glory vines. They look and feel rather like potatoes, but they’re only about a centimeter across, and they are above ground. Is this a disease, or is the Morninglory supposed to produce it? Is it edible, or poisonous?

Comment: pictures please

Comment: @kevinskio Will do…

Comment: @kevinskio I was not able to find any out right now. Maybe I should ask this question later, when they come up again.

Comment: Stem Gall? https://bugguide.net/node/view/582501/bgimage

Comment: @Ecnerwal No. They really look like potatoes. That looks more like a cross between a thistle and an artichoke.